# Owl carousel not following z-index in Wordpress theme

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, owl-carousel

I've implemented Owl Carousel in the header of my Wordpress theme. It is a basic slider with each item containing a background image and an overlay div that will eventually feature information about my blog posts. I also have a fixed navigation bar at the top of my blog. No matter how I style the elements, the Owl Carousel continues to disobey the z-index parameters and scroll on top of my fixed navigation.

Here's the styling of my navigation:

```
.topbar { 
  width:100%;
  color: #fff;
  position:fixed;
  font-family:'Abril Fatface';
  z-index:1;
}
```

And the styling for my carousel:

```
.carousel-wrap {
   max-width: 1200px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 475px!important;
   margin:auto;
   margin-bottom:50px;
   position: relative;
   z-index:100;
}

/* fix blank or flashing items on carousel */
.owl-carousel .item {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 37%;
  height: 450px;
}

/* end fix */
.owl-nav > div {
  margin-top: -26px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  color: #cdcbcd;
}

.owl-nav i {
  font-size: 52px;
}

.owl-nav .owl-prev {
  left: -30px;
}

.owl-nav .owl-next {
  right: -30px;
}
.caroverlay {
   padding:40px;
   text-align: center;
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
   max-width:300px;
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   top:175px;
   left: 40px;
   color:#000;
}
```

Here is the HTML which in placed in my theme's header:

```
<div class="carousel-wrapper">
  <div class="owl-carousel">

    <div class="item" style="background-image: url('https://hdwallsource.com/img/2016/6/zoe-kravitz-celebrity-wide-wallpaper-55692-57437-hd-wallpapers.jpg')">
    <div class="caroverlay">This is some text.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="item" style="background-image: url('http://pixel.nymag.com/imgs/fashion/daily/2017/04/08/08-zoekravitz.w710.h473.2x.jpeg')">
    <div class="caroverlay">This is some text.</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Lastly, here is the JS that I placed in my theme's footer:

```
<script>
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  autoplay: true,
  items: 1,
    singleItem: true,
    itemsScaleUp : true,
})
</script>
```

I've tried everything I can think of and nothing is working. My last attempt was wrapping all of the divs in a container that was set with a low z-index, but that also did not work. [Here is a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX0MR.jpg) Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hello,
You have test with .topbar ====>    'z-index: 999;' // > 1    ?

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't understand. Thanks.

Comment: Change value of **z-index** in your CSS for **TopBar** with value > 100.
Because in **carousel-wrap** z-index = 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the z-index of your topbar navigation to be higher than your carousel's z-index (100).

```
.topbar {  
  z-index:999;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I guess I had my thinking backwards. I thought that a lower z-index number would bring it forward. Brain fart! Thank you so much.